# _bstr_t concatenate gives 12142

Tags: c++, sql, string-concatenation

I have a strange thing here.
I'm concatenating `_bstr_t` strings in order to assemble a SQL command.

```
_bstr_t strSQL = a+b+k+hk+Allin+hk+k+hk
```

...and so on.

When I print it to the console (using `std::wcout <<  '/n'<< strSQL << '/n';`) I get my string, BUT with a 12142 in the beginning and end of the string. It looks like:

```
 12142"SELECT * FROM....."12142
```

Does anyone know where it comes from?

I'm using: VS2010 Express, C++, and I'm building a console app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You wrote '/n' instead of '\n'. This is a multicharacter literal, which in this case gives an integer with the value 12142.

Comment: For the curious: 12142 = 0x2F6E hex, 0x2F = '/', 0x6E = 'n'